# Dim Numbers as integer from a Textbox

Tags: vb.net

how should i do this to work in a textbox?
 Dim Numbers() As Integer = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20}

Not worked:  `Dim Numbers() As Integer = Textbox1.Text`

Comment: So, you have some text representing numbers in a TextBox. What is the content of this TextBox? A sequence of values separated by a comma? By a comma and a space? A single space? Is the separator a *certified* constant? Where do these values come from? User (manual) input? Add the expected content of this/these TextBox(es) to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should work:

```
Dim Numbers() As Integer = TextBox1.Text.Split(",").Select(Function(v) CInt(v)).ToArray()
```

It splits the text by ',' and creates a string array from it. Then it takes all the elements of that string array, converts them to integers, and creates a new array from these.

Answer (score 1):

I have split values by ',' to string array and assign values to Int array.

```
Dim names As IList(Of String) = textBox1.Text.Split(","c)
Dim Numbers As Integer() = New Integer(names.Count - 1) {}

For i As Integer = 0 To names.Count - 1
    Numbers(i) = Convert.ToInt16(names(i))
Next
```